# Closing all buffers that represent .js files?

Tags: buffers

Can I close all buffers by regex, for instance all buffers that hold open `.js` files?

Effectively what I want is

```
:bd *.js
```

But even with `!` if more than one `.js` is open I get,

```
E93: More than one match for *.js
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is answered on a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155461/how-to-delete-multiple-buffers-in-vim) from one on StackOverflow:

Use `<C-A>` to expand the `*.js` on the command line.

This way `:bd *.js` will become `:bd file1.js file2.js file42.js`.

My loop-free answer (in case more control is required) was:

```
function! s:BDExt(ext)
  let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && bufname(v:val) =~ "\.'.a:ext.'$"')
  if empty(buffers) |throw "no *.".a:ext." buffer" | endif
  exe 'bd '.join(buffers, ' ')
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 BDExt :call s:BDExt(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a function to do this:

```
function! CloseByRegex(re)
    for b in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        if bufname(b) =~ re
            exec "bd" b
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

`bufnr('$')` is the number of the last buffer.

Comment: IIRC, `range(bufnr('$'))` will exclude the last buffer number, and it starts at 0, which is no valid buffer.